# Names of image files on a website: hashes or random strings?

Tags: image, filenames, storage

I have read several questions about naming uploaded images, and people usually advise to hash image content for generating unique file name plus auto-preventing storing duplicates. But if two users upload the same image and then one of them want to delete it?
We will need to perform some check for additional owners every time an image is being deleted.

IMHO possibility of duplicated files is usually tiny; at the same time, this check needs a couple strings of code to add and it will cost something in terms of performance (galleries tend to use huge tables).

So, why not to use really random string for name?
In php, for example:

```
$filename = md5(mt_rand());
```

Not to mention that hashes generate quite long values, and with random value you can adjust the length as you wish (keeping in mind that number of variations also changes):

```
$filename = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 15);
```

And with loop for possible collisions (idea stolen from another question):

```
while (true) {
 $filename = substr(md5(mt_rand()), 0, 15);
 if (!file_exists('somedir/'.$filename.'.jpg')) break;
}
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just prefix the image file by the user id, or create a folder for every user? (I think its not a good idea to keep too much file in the same folder.)
As long as it fits your requirements, you can do whatever you want, but the Hash method may be proven more effective.

Comment: I am really newbie in webdev and don't have my own experience of having tons of images, but others say that splitting folders increase performance, like a/b/abcdef.jpg. As for using primary keys, I also wonder why guys in other questions don't talk about this way.

Comment: Creating and reading index for a folder that contains million file will surely slow down the whole process.